# Permissions changed on /dev/nvidia* when GPU accessed as root on SUSE

Tags: suse, nvidia

I've got a Linux box running SLES11SP1 with 4 NVIDIA GPUs in it, for running CUDA programs.

If the GPU is accessed by a process running as root, it changes the permissions on /dev/nvidia{0,1,2,3,ctl} to something inaccessible by non-root users. However, this behavior doesn't seem to occur when running on Ubuntu.

Does anybody know what would cause this behavior on SLES, and how to disable it?

Comment: Are you specifically running a program as root?

Comment: @penguin359 - Sometimes I do specifically run a program as root that needs to access the GPUs. When this happens, the permissions are changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had same issue on SLES11sp1. Only way I could resolve it was to add the LDAP user account to the local machine's video group. I was told you could also change a line in /etc/modprobe.d/50-nvidia.conf from NVreg_DeviceFileMode=0660 to NVreg_DeviceFileMode=0666.

Comment: Setting NVreg_DeviceFileMode=0666 seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Mark’s answer is correct; however, 666 did not work for me. I had to add my username to the video group.

I'm running openSUSE 15 and had the same problem with a multi-gpu setup.

To see which groups you belong to type

```
groups <username>
```

where `<username>` is replaced by your user name.

You can add your username to the video group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G video <username>
```

where `<username>` is, again, replaced by your username. If you were logged in, you'll need to log out and then back in before you can see the changes.